# Determining Valid DTFT's

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, frequency-domain

Are the following frequency domain signals valid DTFT's (Discrete Time Fourier Transforms)? Answer yes or no, and justify your answer.

a) $X(\omega) = \omega + \pi$

b) $X(\omega) = i + \pi$

c) $X(\omega) = \sin(10\omega)$

d) $X(\omega) = \sin(\omega/10)$

---

I'm just very unsure as to how to go about this question (what methodology to use). Could anyone possibly point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't a valid DTFT be $2\pi$-periodic?

Comment: Maybe consulting a [table of DTFTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Table_of_discrete-time_Fourier_transforms) will give you some ideas as to what typical DTFTs look like.